# How can I use the parent class to get a parameter from child class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this child class AggressiveAlien and here is one method inside it

```
public boolean attack()
{
    boolean attack;
    if (currentLocation == this.AggresiveAlien.getCurrentLocation)
    {
        energyCanister = (int) ( (1/2) * alien2.energyCanister + energyCanister);
        lifePoints = (int) (lifePoints - (1/2)*alien2.energyCanister);
        attack = true;
    }
    return attack;
}
```

I would like the returned value to be used in the parent class Alien

```
public void gotAttacked()
{
    if (AggresiveAlien.attack())
        energyCanister = energyCanister/2;
}
```

But it seems to be giving errors on the AggresiveAlien.attack() part. Is there any way for me to use this returned value from AggresiveAlien to be used in Alien?

Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Here is another part of the child class

public class AggressiveAlien extends Alien
{
    public AggressiveAlien(XYCoordination currentLocation, int energyCanister)
    {
        super(currentLocation, energyCanister);
    }

```
public int collectCanister(NormalPlanet canister)
{
    super.collectCanister();
    n=1;
}
```

Comment: What is that error you get "on the AggresiveAlien.attack() part"?

Comment: Hard to tell from what you supplied but it seems that AggressiveAlien isn't the object where the attack function is located?

Comment: Hate to ask this, but did you import `AggressiveAlien`?

Comment: `getCurrentLocation` seems to be a method, but you use it as a field. Shouldn't be `this.AggresiveAlien.getCurrentLocation()`?

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting? Also 1/2 could be written as 0.5 (maybe the compiler already does this, but is much easier to read) and `energyCanister = energyCanister / 2` is better written as `energyCanister /= 2`.

Comment: it says cannot find symbol AggresiveAlien.

Comment: Show us the part of Alien class where you define and set value to AggressiveAlien.

Comment: I think you are confused. Please learn to distinguish between classes and objects.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be having two problems... First you need to cast the base type to the child type, such as

```
((AggressiveAlien)this).attack()
```

Also, 1/2 may actually be 0!  1 and 2 are interpreted as integers which means the value of any division is floored!  so 1/2 = (int) 0.5 = 0

check your types!  You better use 0.5 or use /2.0 to force the value to compute as a float or double (depending on the platform).

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you're trying to use AggresiveAlien statically. Instead you probably want to do:

```
if ((AggresiveAlien)this.attack()) energyCanister = energyCanister/2;
```

But I can't be sure given the limited amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

you say, you have a parent and child class, which means you are using `inheritance` here. you can easily accomplish your task by using virtual function and then overriding in the child class.

in your `Alien` class create a function called `attack()` and override in the child class `AggresiveAlien`.

like following:

**Alien class:**

```
public boolean attack()
{
    return false;
}
```

**AggresiveAlien class:**

```
public boolean attack()
{
    return true;
}
```

**and your gotAttacked function**

```
public void gotAttacked()
{
    if (this.attack())
        energyCanister = energyCanister/2;
}
```